# How does the class inherited from the baseclass

Tags: python, inheritance

Here's a part of the code from CS61A lab10, and I don't know the effect of some code.

```py
    class Expr:
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.args = args
    class Name(Expr):
        def __init__(self, string):
            Expr.__init__(self, string)
            self.string = string
```

The Name class is inherited from Expr class, and has the instance `string`.
However, I don't know what the code   `Expr.__init__(self, string)`  for. It seems meaningless and I can run the whole code without this line. So why we need this line?

Thanks for the help

Comment: That's a question for whoever wrote the two classes. All you can say for sure is that `Name("foo")` produces an object with two attributes: `string`, which is set to `"foo"`; and `args`, which is set to `("foo",)`. Whether that is the intent is impossible to tell from the code alone.

Comment: Put another way, the call to `Expr.__init__` is optional, in the sense that it's not a syntax error or anything to omit it. But it is *not* optional if some code you don't show expects a `Name` object to have an `args` attribute set the way `Expr.__init__` sets it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you concrete example it is indeed  meaningless, but the actual behavior is:

- On **Name** class you are calling Expr constructor
- The **Expr** constructor saves it's parameter into an instance variable `self.args`
- At the end the instance will have 2 ways to access the string argument:

`instance.args`
and
`instance.string`

Also, that's not the correct way to call a parent constructor, you should use the following:

**python 2.x**

```py
class Name(Expr):
    def __init__(self, string):
        super(Name, self).__init__(string)
        self.string = string
```

**python 3.x**

```py
class Name(Expr):
    def __init__(self, string):
        super().__init__(string)
        self.string = string
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your `Expr` class is inherited by the `Name` class.

When you inherit from another class, you need to call the constructor function (i.e. `__init__()`) of the parent class (`Expr`) into the child class (`Name`).

Comment: It's usually a good idea (if you want your object to be correctly initialized), but it isn't strictly *necessary*.